# Customize look of select options

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to customize the highlight color, when a mouse rolls over options, in select drop-down menu? In IE and FF it appears royal blue. Can it be changed with CSS or jQuery?

```
<select class="mySelect">
   <option value="1">White
   <option value="2">Black
   <option value="3">Red
</select>
```

Also, is it possible to change color of the current option background when the drop-down appears below?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to close your options with </option>

Comment: Have you tried fiddling with `option:hover`?

Comment: yes, does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely limited, if not impossible in IE. I've used the Uniform plugin for jQuery a few times for a cross-browser solution. You could also create a fake drop down menu with a list and some JS to handle the behaviour.

http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/

Comment: Yes, I saw that plugin. I don't think I want to add that layer of complexity just to change the look. Thanks.